# SQL statment SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QLink = id doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm working on an app and I ran into a problem which has been messing with my head for hours and I can't figure it out.

This is part of the code:

```
int id = getID();
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QLink = " + id, null);
int count = cursor.getCount();
```

So the problem is that count always equals 0 but it shouldn't. I already checked if the id is wrong which it isn't. I got some results when I removed everything after and including WHERE so the table is fine. The QLink field type is INTEGER, maybe I should replace that with something else like NUMERIC ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QLink = '" + id + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bindings?

```
String id = Integer.toString(getID())
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QLink = ?", new String[]{id});
```

Comment: I have now but still no results. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

1) Is QLink the right column name?

2) Try to run this before running `.getCount()`

```
moveToFirst()
```

i remembered the query won't run until you execute something before using the `.getCount()`

3) Have you tried?

```
db.query("Answers", 
  new String[] { "whatever columns" }, 
  "QLink = ?", new String[] { id }, null, null, null);
```

or

```
db.query("Answers", 
      new String[] { "whatever columns" }, 
      "QLink = " + id, null, null, null, null);
```

or

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("select * from answers where qlink = ?");
stmt.bindLong(1, id);
stmt.execute();
```

you probably might need to change your data type for qlink.

Tutorial: http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/3/#getrowasarray

Comment: I tried all of the above but no success yet. What data type should I change QLink to ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been testing it, and this is my opinion. I hope help you.

I create table with 'QLink' column with INTEGER TYPE.

and I insert date throw by SQLite Browser(one of sqlite program).

The problem is that 'QLink' column is definately INTEGER TYPE, 
but i could insert **'4   '** or **' 4'**, which means that's not integer type, that is string type with space.

I execute query message like this "select * from TEST_TABLE where QLink = 4;", there was no result.

I try again with this, "select * from TEST_TABLE where QLink = '4 ';", and there was result of it.

I'm rarely use sqlite, so I'm not professional. 
But I don't understand why I could insert string value to INTEGER TYPE column.

I recommend you check that ID value has blank string on table, and i hope u find answer.